# Can Snort or Suricata *edit* packet on the fly?

Tags: firewalls, ids, packet

I know that they can *detect* traffic by rules, but can they modify packets on the go?

For example, *not only* detecting HTTP GET *but also* adding headers to the GET packet.

If they can't, is there an open source program that can do this at a network scale?

Comment: You might find [Trudy](https://github.com/praetorian-inc/trudy) and [Mallory](https://github.com/intrepidusgroup/mallory) helpful.

Comment: *"... do this at a network scale"* - whatever this exactly is. SoHo networks, small companies, enterprise, ISP, ... all have networks but at  a widely different scale.

Answer (score 1):

Snort and Suricata work on the packet level. While they can reassemble a TCP stream for analysis spanning multiple packets they have not the ability for making changes to the data stream which involve changing the length of the data, i.e. adding some HTTP headers or removing content.

While it is possible in inline mode to [replace](http://manual-snort-org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node34.html#SECTION00476000000000000000) some content with another content the length of the content cannot change. Otherwise all following outgoing and incoming packets in the TCP stream would need to be changed as well in order to match the shift in TCP sequence numbers caused by the modification. It might even be necessary to include new packets into the stream, properly deal with the TCP window etc. At the end this would mean to implement a complete TCP stack and all these changes would also significantly impact the performance.

> If they can't, is there an open source program that can do this at a network scale?

Modifying the traffic in a significant way is the domain of application layer gateways (proxies) which can also be added transparently into the network path. For  HTTP one could use for example the squid proxy. It comes with some the built-in functionality for checking and modifying the traffic (ACLs, adding header...). For more advanced modification one can provide own ideas using the ICAP or eCAP API.